# Object value mysteriously changed

Tags: php, laravel

I'm querying some data from MySQL database using the Laravel framework. I will not be posting the entire query as it's quite long.

```
$logs = DB::query('SELECT ... FROM .. JOIN ... WHERE .. GROUP BY .. ORDER BY');
```

I'm iterating through the results using a simple foreach loop and generating a report using PHPExcel as follows:

```
foreach($logs as $log):
 ...
endforeach;
```

Inside the loop, I am calculating the difference between the two dates in month as follows:

```
$cntr_startdate = new DateTime($log->start_date);
$cntr_enddate = new DateTime($log->end_date);                   
$conterm = $cntr_enddate->diff($cntr_startdate);
$cterm = (($conterm->format('%y') * 12) + $conterm->format('%m'));
```

After the following line, the rate field in $log object is somehow corrupted and returns garbage like b, X, and O.5 (the remaining fields are untouched).

```
$cterm = (($conterm->format('%y') * 12) + $conterm->format('%m'));
```

What could be causing the loss of data?

Comment: If you remove the lines that use PHPExcel to generate the report, does this loss still happen? My guess is that PHPExcel is messing with your computer's RAM.

Comment: I've tried that. PHPExcel doesn't affect it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the MySQL TIMESTAMPDIFF function and let MySQL do the calculation for you. I think that this would be more efficient, anyway.

Comment: Thanks man, TIMESTAMPDIFF works great. Though the problem with PHP datediff still remains dark.